# Calculate the line integral (cyl. coords)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

So I have this vector field

$$
\textbf{B}=K \left( \frac{\cos \varphi}{\rho^2}\textbf{e}_{\rho}+ \left( \frac{\sin \varphi}{\rho^2}+ \frac{1}{a\rho}\textbf{e}_{\varphi} \right) \right)
$$
and the first part of the problem is to calculate a potential which I have done. So the potential is
$$
\phi(\rho,\varphi,z)=-K\frac{\cos\varphi}{\rho}+\frac{K}{a}\varphi
$$
Now to the problem. I'm asked to calculate the line integral

$$
\int_C \textbf{B} \cdot d\textbf{r}
$$
where $C: \textbf{r}(s)=(b\cos(s),b\sin(s),b), \, 0≤s≤2\pi, \, b>0$

I can't do this with the potential, because of the singularities, right? When I try to compute the line integral by the parametrization it just gets messy and I can't integrate it. Can anyone show me how to do this last part or point me in the right direction?

Comment: The potential does not look right ($\partial\phi/\partial\varphi$ does not have $\rho^2$). It is something strange with the parentheses in the field definition too.

Comment: You are forgetting the scalar factor, the potential should be right according to my professors notes.

Comment: ok, you mean $1/\rho$ comes from the variable change. But what singularities are you talking about? Do you mean the origin? The field and the potential look good along the path.

Comment: In cylindrical coords we have that 
$$
grad\phi = \frac{1}{h_{\rho}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \rho} \textbf{e}_{\rho}+ \frac{1}{h_{\varphi}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \varphi}\textbf{e}_{\varphi} + \frac{1}{h_{z}}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\textbf{e}_{z}
$$
and we have that scaling factor $h_{\varphi}=\rho$.
When it comes to the potential I'm not sure, maybe my professor is wrong then? Because under the problem he wrote "Note: because $\textbf{B}$ is singular, you can not use the potential". Maybe it's not true for all $b$?

Comment: It comes from the $\phi$ term in the potential. Going around $z$-axis will result in $2\pi$ jump. I guess you can use the potential, but carefully..

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write my interpretation of how I understand it. We have to calculate the work of the vector field (=the line integral) along the path $C$.

**Method 1:** Direct parametrization (by definition).
$$
\textbf{B} \cdot d\textbf{r}=[\text{in cyl. coord.}]=(B_\rho, B_\phi,B_z)\cdot (d\rho,\rho\,d\varphi,dz)=K\Bigl(\frac{\cos\varphi}{\rho^2}\,d\rho+\Bigl(\frac{\sin\varphi}{\rho}+\frac{1}{a}\Bigr)\,d\varphi\Bigr).
$$
Along the path we have $\rho=b$, that is $d\rho=0$, and $\varphi=s$, hence, the integral becomes
$$
K\int_0^{2\pi}\Bigl(\frac{\sin s}{b}+\frac{1}{a}\Bigr)\,ds=K\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a}\,ds=\frac{2\pi K}{a}.
$$
**Method 2:** Using the potential. Since in the new variables the vector field and the potential has no singularities along the path, we have that
$$
\int_C \textbf{B} \cdot d\textbf{r}=\phi(\text{end point})-\phi(\text{start point})=\phi(b,2\pi,b)-\phi(b,0,b)=\frac{K}{a}2\pi.
$$
**Interpretation:** The field can be split into two
$$
\textbf{B}=\textbf{B}_1+\textbf{B}_2
$$
where
$$
\textbf{B}_1=K \left( \frac{\cos \varphi}{\rho^2}\textbf{e}_{\rho}+\frac{\sin \varphi}{\rho^2}\textbf{e}_{\varphi}\right)=[xyz-\text{coord}]=
\left(\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2},\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2},0\right)
$$
which is a potential field with the potential $-K\frac{\cos\varphi}{\rho}=-K\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ (I am not very sure, but it looks like some kind of vector field of the electrostatic line dipole), and
$$
\textbf{B}_2=K\frac{1}{a\rho}\textbf{e}_{\varphi}=[xyz-\text{coord}]=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},0\right)
$$
which is the magnetic field around the infinite wire along the $z$ axis. The first field has zero work since the potential does not depend on $z$ and the start and the end points of the curve have the same $x,y$ coordinates. So the only contribution to the work comes from the second field with the known property that the work is proportional to the number of rotations around the wire times $2\pi$.

Comment: I'll take this as an answer :) Since I don't understand what my professor mean and this makes sense :) thank you!

Comment: @Danny Maybe your professor mean that the vector field is not potential in $xyz$-coordinates? A potential field would have zero line integral along any closed curve. Here we have the closed curve, starting and ending at $(b,0,b)$, but the integral is not zero because of singularities on $z$-axis. When we change to cylindrical coordinates, the singularities disappear, the field becomes potential, but the path is no longer closed.